# Field automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$

Tags: field-theory, rational-functions

Determine all the field automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ of order two.

I know that every field automorphism must be the identity map over $\mathbb{Q}$, and so they are uniquely determined given the image of $x$. For example consider
$$ \varphi: \mathbb{Q}(x) \to \mathbb{Q}(x) \quad \varphi(x) = \frac{1}{x} $$
Then $\varphi$ is a well defined automorpfism and $\varphi \circ \varphi (x) = x$ which means it has order two.

I've alredy proved that in general if $\varphi(x) = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$, then 
$$\deg P - \deg Q = \pm 1$$

And also that $x \to -x$ and $x \to -\frac{1}{x}$ are two trivial automorphisms. Can you help me saying something more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each automorphism of $\Bbb Q(x)$ satisfies
$$\phi(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$
with $ad-bc\ne0$.
Associating this with the matrix $A=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$
shows the automorphism group is isomorphic to $\text{PSL}_2(\Bbb Q)$.
This represents a degree two automorphism iff $A$ is not a scalar
matrix but $A^2$ is. This boils down to $A$ having trace zero, that is
$d=-a$.

Comment: can you please give me reference or proof for the first fact you used?

Comment: If $y=f(x)/g(x)$ then $|\Bbb Q(x):\Bbb Q(y)|=\max(\deg f,\deg g)$.